# NavigationDrawer remove shadow

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

What I want to have is a NavigationDrawer that is connected seemless to the main content likee in the design below:

[image: design]

Somehow I can't get the shadow from the drawer.

What I tried is this:

```
drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
drawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.transparent, GravityCompat.START);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    drawer.setElevation(0f);
}
```

setScrimColor for removing the whole dimming effect but the shadow is still there:

[image: screenshot]

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigationViews" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Unless you're in an RTL layout, I believe you should be using `GravityCompat.START`.

Comment: @Mike M. Had that first, no effect. But thanks! I'll update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the backgroundcolor from the LinearLayout and move it to the parent Drawerlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigationViews" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Why? I think when the drawerlayout predicts that the drawer has a different background than the mainlayout, it draws a shadow, no matter what setting. I'm not sure, I haven't looked into the source code of Android.

Answer (score 3):

Add following codes to your JAVA class.

```
drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
drawer.setDrawerElevation(0);
```

Comment: You can also remove elevation directly in XML: app:elevation="0dp"